Does there exist an ultrafilter of $\mathbb{R}$ with fixed accumulation point property
This question arose from a real analysis question, where i am more generally looking for a finitely additive measure on $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ for a fixed point $a$ that satisfies the property:
$\forall A \in 2^{\mathbb{R}}: a\notin \overline{A-\{a\}} \implies P(A)=0$
Since an ultrafilter is a finitely additive 0-1-measure and restricting the measure to 0 and 1 would give nice properties to the core question, an ultrafilter satisfying above property would be amazing. However since the property ensures the ultrafilter has to be free (finite sets don't have accumulation points), an explicit construction in ZF is impossible. Is the existence of such a filter assuming AC possible?

Your requirement seems to imply that every interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ has the full measure (probability $1$).  How could such a probability measure be anything other than the pointmass at $a$?

@MikhailKatz Without countable additivity, it need not be the case that ${a}=\bigcap_n (a-1/n,a+1/n)$ has measure $1$.

@MikhailKatz Yes, the question only asks for a finitely additive measure.

As a matter of fact the additional condition is contradictory with countable additivity, by the countable partition with sets of the forms ]a+1/n,a+1/(n-1)], [a-1/(n-1),a-1/n[,{a} of which all cannot be part of said ultrafilter.

For each natural number $m$, let $F_m=\{a+1/n\mid n\geq m\}$. The family $\{F\mid F\supseteq F_m,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a free filter. Every filter is contained in an ultrafilter, so this filter extends to a free ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$.
To see that it has the desired property, assume that $a\notin \overline{A-\{a\}}$. Then, for some neighborhood $U$ of $a$, $U\cap A\subseteq\{a\}$. For some $m$, we must have $F_m\subseteq U$. This implies $F_m\cap A=\emptyset$ and, therefore, $A\notin\mathcal{U}$.

Thank you this is what i was looking for!

I just want to note that the family of ultrafilters i was looking for exactly coincides with those containing the filter induced by the prefilter of a-excludibg neighbourhoods of a
